# Use oracle multitenant database for development purpose

Tags: oracle, multi-tenant, oracle12c

I have just read the whitepaper about oracle 12c's new feature called `multitenant database`.

What are the drawbacks to setup the software development infrastructure with this technology as follows? As the name of this new feature suggests, the proper purpose is totally different from this approach.

```
CDB (Oracle 12c multitenant container database)
|
|--- PDB  (pluggable Development Database)
|
|--- PDB  (pluggable Testing Database)
|
|--- PDB  (pluggable Production Database)
```

I assume this should be much cheaper than three separate database licences?

The multitenant architecture supports plugging a PDB into a CDB whose Oracle Database 
software version differs from that of the CDB from which it was unplugged. Therefore database upgrades should also be no problem?

Comment: Not sure it's ever safe to assume anything about Oracle licencing. [Having multiple PDBs is an extra-cost option](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBLIC/editions.htm#CIHBAEID).

Comment: @Alex Poole  I agree :-) The price of multitenant option is the same as the price of a standard edition database, see http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf  Therefore it's cheaper than two enterprise edition databases, is'nt it?

Comment: As I understood it, you get to create 1 container database and 1 pluggable database with a standard edition license.

Comment: What about patching? Patching is at CDB level. Don't you want to test the patch in Dev/Test before?

Comment: @vercelli you are right, it's not possible to patch a single pdb. this is a show-stopper.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will probably not put the production PDB in the same CDB as the development one. Even if they have some isolation (resources, security, namespace) they are managed by the same instance.
2. It is not cheaper for licensing because you never license per database. It is per-user or per processors. Actually, having more than one PDB in a CDB is an option and is more expensive than having 2 single-tenant CDBs.
3. Upgrades are still a problem because the PDB must be upgraded once plugged into a higher version CDB. However, this will be faster and more automated in 18c
4. The advantages are consolidation and lot of features for data movement (for example you can clone or move a PDB online while the application is running)

Regards,
Franck